# Joining friends to other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I'm still having trouble building complex joins in ActiveRecord.

I have a User model that is using the [HasManyFriends](https://github.com/swemoney/has_many_friends) plugin by Steve Ehrenberg (http://dnite.org).

Then I have a UserFeedEvent model that links users to a FeedEvent model.

What I'd like to achieve is to **find all the FeedEvents linked to the friends of a User**.

How should I write my ActiveRecord query?

Here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many_friends

  has_many :feed_events, :through => :user_feed_events, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :user_feed_events, :dependent => :destroy

end


class UserFeedEvent < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :feed_event, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :user

end


class FeedEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_feed_events, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :user_feed_events

  serialize :data
end
```

Thanks in advance!
Augusto

Comment: Why is this not just User.feed_events ?

Comment: That is perfect to list the FeedEvents of a specific user, what I'd like instead is to list all the FeedEvents of all the friends of a specific user.   Something like: User.friends.feed_events (but this doesn't work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working and more traditional SQL solution:

```
friends_id = current_user.friends.collect {|f| f.id}.join(",")

sql = "SELECT feed_events.*, user_feed_events.user_id  FROM feed_events LEFT JOIN user_feed_events ON feed_events.id = user_feed_events.feed_event_id WHERE user_feed_events.user_id IN (#{friends_id}) GROUP BY feed_events.id ORDER BY feed_events.created_at DESC"

friend_feed_events = FeedEvent.paginate_by_sql(sql, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
```

If you have a more efficient / more elegant way of doing the same, please let me know!

Comment: Alternatively you could use `has_many :friend_feeds, :class = > "FeedEvent", :finder_sql => ...` as shown in [has_many](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) documentation, so you could use `current_user.friend_feeds`

Answer (score 1):

Digging through *HasManyFriends* source leads me to believe that the following should work (or be half-way through):

**EDIT:** found out that `source` cannot point to another `:has_many :through` association. So you could try the updated version.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  has_many :user_feed_events_of_friends_by_me, :through => :friends_by_me,
    :source => :user_feed_events
  has_many :feed_events_of_friends_by_me, :through => :user_feed_events_by_me

  has_many :user_feed_events_of_friends_for_me, :through => :friends_for_me,
    :source => :user_feed_events
  has_many :feed_events_of_friends_for_me, :through => :user_feed_events_for_me

  # A wrapper to return full list of two-way friendship events
  def feeds_events_of_my_friends
    self.feed_events_of_friends_by_me + self.feed_events_of_friends_for_me
  end
end
```

Unfortunately the `HMF` plugin has two one-way friendship links, which means full list requires 2 DB queries.

Comment: Thank you Laas! 

I tried your solution but I get this error and I don't know how to solve it :(

ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationMacroError: Invalid source reflection macro :has_many :through for has_many :feed_events_of_friends_by_me, :through => :friends_by_me.  Use :source to specify the source reflection.

Comment: Maybe I misread the source or it has changed since your version (I looked it up from GitHub). What you need to do, is look up (e.g in console) what is the name of the relation that points to friends one way and the other way too. Then change the code appropriately.

Comment: What do you mean by the "name of the relation that points to friends one way and the other way too"?  In my console doing user. friends_by_me works, but using it in your relation results in the previous error.

Comment: More specifically the error is: ctiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `user_feed_events`.* FROM `user_feed_events`  INNER JOIN `users` ON `user_feed_events`.user_id = `users`.id    WHERE ((`users`.user_id = 6) AND ((accepted_at IS NOT NULL)))